# How can I use Nextjs Link Component with framer motion in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, next.js, types, typeerror, framer-motion

### Description

I want to animate a nextjs Link component using framer motion. I'm also using TypeScript and It keeps giving me a type error of:

`Property 'Link' does not exist on type '(<Props extends {}>(Component: string | ComponentType<PropsWithChildren<Props>>, customMotionComponentConfig?: CustomMotionComponentConfig | undefined) => CustomDomComponent<...>) & HTMLMotionComponents & SVGMotionComponents'. Did you mean 'link'?`

### Code

Here's the component I'm making.

```ts
export default function Button({ href, text, type, ...props }: ButtonTypes) {
  console.log(styles);
  if (href) {
    return (
      <motion.Link
        href={href}
        type={type}
        className={`${styles['neon-button']} focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-aquamarine`}
        {...props}
      >
        {text}
      </motion.Link>
    );
  }
  return (
    <motion.button
      whileHover={{ scale: 1.1 }}
      whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
      type={type}
      className="neon-button focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-aquamarine"
      {...props}
    >
      {text}
    </motion.button>
  );
}
```

### Expectations

The component animates when I add the whileHover and whileTap properties, but obviously I need to get rid of the type error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do so by wrapping Component in `motion()` function.

```
const Component = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <div ref={ref} />
))

const MotionComponent = motion(Component)
```

```
const MotionLink= motion(Link)
```

[Framer Custom Component](https://www.framer.com/motion/component/#custom-components)

If you don't like this there are some workarounds as well:

**Workaround 1**:
One possible work around is to wrap your next Link in a div and use framer motion on wrapper div.

```
<motion.div
   className={styles.linkWrapper}
   //your framer motion props goes here
>
  <Link href="#"> Lorem </Link>
</motion.div>
```

--

**Workaround 2:**
Use `<motion.a>` tag instead of `<Link>` and use `useRouter` to implement functionality of `Link` on `a` tag.

Example:

```
const router = useRouter()
```

```
 <motion.a
    href="/contact"
    onClick={(e) => {
       e.preventDefault();
       router.push("/contact");
    }}
    className={styles.navLink}
 >
    Lorem
</motion.a>
```

Learn more at: [Next useRouter Hook official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/use-router)

Answer (score 0):

The TypeScript error is caused by the fact that `<motion.Link>` does not exist in Motion's API. Motion only supports DOM primitives (so basic HTML elements, like `<a>` and `<button>`, which is why `motion.button` does work without issues) and `Link` is a NextJS component.

See https://www.framer.com/motion/component/#custom-components for how you can create a custom Motion component that wraps NextJS' `Link` component. That would get rid of the TS error as well.